# static files not detected Django 1.10

Tags: python, django

**Problem**: javascript and css files doesn't load.
I am using Django 1.10, my
`settings.py` file looks like this:

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_root")
```

I have my static files in the `static folder` and also have a static root, still the `js`, `css` not working
Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What error are you getting? What are you seeing that you do not expect to? Have you read up on collectstatic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify it in `urls.py` file as well

```
# need these two additional imports
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
  ...
]

# add this extra line of code
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Have you done that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using *runserver* in Debug mode, you don't need to modify your URLs.

Your settings look fine provided that your directory structure looks like:

```
- myProject
  - myProject
    - settings.py
  - static
  - ...
```

Have you remembered to add `{ load staticfiles }` at the top of your templates?

In that case, `{% url 'css/whatever.css' }` should work.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but the change in `urls.py` is solving the issue for me now, thanks anyways for your time.

Comment: @hash in that case, you probably don't have `django.contrib.staticfiles` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. It's bad practice to modify your URLs like that since in production, you should be serving them with nginx/apache pointed to your `STATIC_ROOT` folder.